# jenkins ci build user's group not correct

Tags: unix, jenkins

For building our software, there is a build group. This is for writing some files to certain location which the group has write permissions to.

I have set the the jenkins user to be part of that group. But the build process fails due to "permission denied".

To debug, i got statements to print out the real and effective gid of the process. If i run the same command as jenkins user from the shell, the group is correct, i.e, the build group. But through jenkins, its the default group of jenkins i.e, "jenkins" itself.

How can i make jenkins to use the correct group?

System Information:

OS : RHEL5
Jenkins Version : 1.414

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the jenkins server loaded the group information.

Comment: Wow, I had to restart the slaves for it to read the new groups?

Comment: Nearly 5 years and this bug has still not been fixed! Thanks for the question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your slave is probably running as whoever you installed it as, which may be different then the build user. Configure your slave in Jenkins, to install as your build user.